# auto update projects on Nexus Repository Manager when pushing to private Gitlab

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, nexus3

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

I am currently working on workflow performance.

My Idea is, when I push changes from IntelliJ to a private GitLab Server; I would like that my GitLab instantly create a finished .jar file from new code and push it to my Nexus Repo Manager.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a post-commit hook to run your build script.

See [this link about custom hooks](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/administration/custom_hooks.md)

The hook filename will be `/path/to/your/<project>.git/custom_hooks/post-commit`

And the contents of `post-commit` would launch your build script.